# How to send comments from a UIViewController to another UIViewController and to store them in an array?

Tags: ios, swift

When I tap on a cell from my TableView a PopUp ViewController will show up and from there I want to send comments to Main UIViewController using delegates.
In the Main ViewController I want to store that comments in an Array of strings and after that to show that comments in each cell from my TableView.
The problem is that is crashing with error `Fatal error: Index out of range` because I don't have any comments at beginning.

If I go in function `numberOfRowsInSection` and I return the `commentsArray.count` then I will won't be able to click on any cell anymore to show my popup.
Is  there a way to remove this error without to affect my code from `numberOfRowsInSection` ?

Here is my code:

```
class MainVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var questionsTableView: UITableView!

    var commentReceived = [String]()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        switch section {
        case 0: return 1 // This need to be 1
        case 1: return 2 // This need to be 2
        default: return 1
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MainVCCell
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.configCell()

        cell.commentLabel.text = commentReceived[indexPath.row] // ERROR HERE -> Fatal error: Index out of range

        return cell
    }

    // implemented protocol
    func receivedComment(comment: String?) {
        commentReceived.append(comment ?? "")
        questionsTableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "goToPopUp" {
            let popUpVC = segue.destination as! PopUpVC
            popUpVC.delegate = self
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your numberOfRows should be based on count of commentReceived array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hardcoding `numberOfSections` here, if your `data array` is empty you should return 0.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if commentReceived.isEmpty {
        return 0
    }
    return 2
}
```

Or replace this line 
`cell.commentLabel.text = commentReceived[indexPath.row]`

with

```
if !commentReceived.isEmpty {
  cell.commentLabel.text = commentReceived[indexPath.row]
}
```

if you want to show an `empty cell` first. Don't `return 0` in this case.